# PHP/server can't handle large numbers?

Tags: php, string, api, 64-bit, 32-bit

We are using a payment API which sents us a Customer Token ID which we then us to access personal data on the API.

An example of the Customer Token ID is 9253691936959900 however PHP is converting this to 9.2536919369599E+15 (for example).  Obviously 9.2536919369599E+15 is a scientific notation and is of no use to us we use it to call the API.

We have tried various conversions such as number_format(9.2536919369599E+15,16) but had no joy.

We are on a 32 bit server and on a PHP 5.4.15.

We have exhausted almost every option, even the developers of the API are struggling to see the issue.  They are certain the Customer Token ID is being sent as a string but for some reason our system is interpreting it as an integer and converting it to a scientific notation.

Any help or advice would be much appreciated.

Thanks a million :)

Comment: you could try forcing it to string when php recieves the value i.e    $var = (string) $var2;

Comment: @Martin it's already converted to scientific notation in $var2 so in fact your are casting the scientific notation presentation of the $var2 not the big int.

Comment: @bolbol Could he not cast to string when sending rather than at the point of receiving? Or is it still notated at this point?

Comment: @Martin that should be the solution. He should cast it before storing it in a variable, otherwise you will lose the int presentation of the number.

Answer (score 2):

PHP is limited to maximum integer number which is `2^63-1` = `9223372036854775807` (this is for 64-bit platform. Other platforms may be much less than this).

Any number larger than max will be converted to floating number.

You have few options:

1. Use strings for ID.
2. Use numbers less than `2^63`
3. Use [PHP GMP library](http://php.net/manual/en/book.gmp.php).

Answer (score -1):

If your API provider returns the key in JSON format:

```
$key = '{"key":999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999}' ;
$a = json_decode($key, true, 2 , JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING);

print $a['key'];
```

The result of above print is: 999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999